# Creating a double linked list problems

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

My problem is that when I try to print this 10 element list nothing happens in Eclipse. I read that its because of Null pointer exception somewhere but I can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
DLinkedList* createList()
{
    int i=0;
    DLinkedList* head = NULL;
    DLinkedList* temp = NULL;
    DLinkedList* temp2 = NULL;

    temp = (DLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(DLinkedList));
    temp2 = (DLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(DLinkedList));
    temp->sensorData = readSensor()->sensorData;
    temp->next = NULL;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            head->prev = NULL;
            printf("1 \t");
        }
        else
        {
            temp2 = head;
            while(temp2->next != NULL)
            {
                temp2 = temp2->next;
            }
            temp2->next = temp;
            temp->prev = temp2;
            printf("2 \t");
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please describe the layout of your data (here, the `DLinkedList` typedef) when you are submitting a question. Also take the habit to check the value returned by `malloc()`, and to clear the values in the space returned (here you are doing it only halfway by clearing `temp->next` but neither `temp->prev` nor any of `temp2`). Then to see debugging intermediaries, you should use `fprintf(stderr...`; and then add more tests when it fails.
Anyway, to return 10 elements you need to allocate 10 elements; also your code only performs single linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the loop, `temp` points at the same chunk of memory, which represents a single node.  You are repeatedly setting the `next` and `prev` pointers of that node to point at itself.

It looks to me that this would result in an infinite loop while you're trying to build the list.  After the second iteration, walking the list would never end, as each time you step to the next node you are really looking at the same node.

You probably want to reinitialize `temp` with a new malloc call on each iteration of the loop, so you actually get distinct nodes.

(Also, there is no need to initialize `temp2` with a malloc. You never do anything with that memory.  The first use of `temp2` is to assign it the value of `head` which points it somewhere else.)